# I fell into the Cloud Sea at Torigoth. How do I get back on land?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

I accidentally fell into the Cloud Sea while exploring Torigoth. I swam around for a while, but I can't find any stairs or a ladder to get back on land.

How do I get out of the Cloud Sea in Torigoth?

[image: Swimming in the cloud sea]

Answer (score 0):

According to [GameFAQs](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/204208-xenoblade-chronicles-2/76056318), it's not a glitch, and either you swim around and find some land somewhere to climb back on, or fast travel out.

Comment: Where can I find land to get back ashore?

Comment: @Stevoisiak - Dunno. Maybe ask that as a different question?